# In the Golden Calf massacre, were the Levites only the executioners or also the judges?

Tags: beit-din-court, levites-leviyim, golden-calf-egel

After the Golden Calf worshipping, Moses commands the Leviites to go out and kill the infidels:

> וַיֹּאמֶר לָהֶם כֹּה־אָמַר ה' אֱלֹהֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל שִׂימוּ אִישׁ־חַרְבּוֹ עַל־יְרֵכוֹ
> עִבְרוּ וָשׁוּבוּ מִשַּׁעַר לָשַׁעַר בַּמַּחֲנֶה
> וְהִרְגוּ אִישׁ־אֶת־אָחִיו וְאִישׁ אֶת־רֵעֵהוּ וְאִישׁ אֶת־קְרֹבוֹ׃
> He said to them, “Thus says the LORD, the God of Israel: Each of you put sword on thigh, go back and forth from gate to gate throughout the camp, and slay brother, neighbor, and kin.” [Exodus.32.27](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.32.27?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=he)

Were those Levites only the executioners of the existing courts that already sentenced the infidels to death or were they themselves the judges?